# Array and for insted of a lot of code

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Right now I have made ​​a macro that create two chart that take values from different sheets.
I think right now there is too much code. and I want to reduce it somehow.

heres my code

```
Sub AddChart(namn As String, UxV As String, UyV As String, AxV As String, AyV As String, ExV As     String, EyV As String, CA As Integer)

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects.Add(200, 200, 600, 400).Chart
    .Parent.Name = namn

    If Not .HasTitle Then
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = namn
    End If

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = CA
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Us"
        .XValues = UxV
        .Values = UyV
    End With

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Ai"
        .XValues = AxV
        .Values = AyV
    End With

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         .Name = "Eu"
         .XValues = ExV
         .Values = EyV
    End With
End With
End Sub
--------------------

Sub calsub()


Dim n As String
Dim CA As Integer
Dim UxT As String
Dim UyT As String
Dim AxT As String
Dim AyT As String
Dim ExT As String
Dim EyT As String

Dim n2 As String
Dim CA2 As Integer
Dim UxP As String
Dim UyP As String
Dim AxP As String
Dim AyP As String
Dim ExP As String
Dim EyP As String

n = "Temperature"
SxT = "=US!A2:A372"
SyT = "=US!C2:C370"
NxT = "=AI!A2:A472"
NyT = "=AI!C2:C472"
FxT = "=EU!A2:A572"
FyT = "=EU!C2:C572"
CA = -20

n2 = "Precipitation"
SxP = "=US!A2:A372"
SyP = "=US!D2:D372"
NxP = "=AI!A2:A371"
NyP = "=AI!D2:D371"
FxP = ""
FyP = ""
CA = -100

Call AddChart(n, UxT, UyT, AxT, AyT, ExT, EyT, CA)
Call AddChart(n2, UxP, UyP, AxP, AyP, ExP, EyP, CA)

End Sub
```

I'm thinking about to creat it like below somehow

```
Sub AddChart(namn As String, xV() As String, yV() As String, CA As Integer) <------

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects.Add(200, 200, 600, 400).Chart
    .Parent.Name = namn

    If Not .HasTitle Then
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = namn
    End If

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = CA
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

for -----------> 

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Us"
        .XValues = UxV
        .Values = UyV
    End With

next <-----------

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not the type of question SO is designed for, I'm afraid. You need to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and maybe break it down into smaller questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if your ranges stay the same, you could use something like

```
For each wks in activeworkbook.worksheets
```

or make up an array of relevant worksheets to loop through.

Then you would have

`.Name = wksArray(i).name` or `.Name = wks.name` istead of `.Name = "Us"'

your array could also be multidimensional, so you could code something like:

```
    .Name = array(i,1).name
    .XValues = array(i,2)
    .Values = array(i,3)
```

Comment: sorry i'm a bit confused.. can u specify it a bit more?

Comment: dito - what are you confused about?! try looking up some informations about multidimension arrays and worksheet-object

Comment: i'm sorry! i was so tierd yesterday so i was abit confused. but i did solvedit thx to u.